# mod_rewrite issue with single file no query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to use mod-rewrite to alter the address bar versus the actual page that's being loaded. It works great when I have a query string to use, but I need to do it without a query string, just a straight up pretty url.

It seems to be that without a query string, straight mod_rewrites to files just shows the actual filename with extension.

Here's what my htaccess looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/account/([^/]*)/$ /adminconfig/account.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This doesn't:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/account/$ /adminconfig/account.php [L]
```

What's happening is that in the address bar I see:

```
example.com/adminconfig/account.php/
```

should be:

```
example.com/admin/account/
```

Comment: invert the order of the RewriteRules

Comment: Reversing them gives me a error 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your rules like this. I also made sure multiviews was off

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?$ /adminconfig/$1.php [L]
```

This rule should allow you to use a URL like this below in the address bar

```
example.com/admin/account/
```

Comment: Thank you! had a peak at mt httpd.conf file, and it was forcing MultiViews on. Being that I don't want to turn it off 100% of the time, this worked well for me.